# coldfusion, sort a struct on a key value

Tags: sorting, struct

I need to re order an array of objects based on a certain key in the object,
the array may look like this, but need it re-ordered so the sequence is in order

```
items: [
    {
        name: 'string',
        sequence: 1,
        detail: 'string'
    },
    {
        name: 'string',
        sequence: 500,
        detail: 'string'
    },
    {
        name: 'string',
        sequence: 33,
        detail: 'string'
    },
    {
        name: 'string',
        sequence: 4,
        detail: 'string'
    }
]
```

once i have the items in order I can loop with confidence that the actions will happen in sequence,
the problems is the client can deliver this array in any sequence, and some clients may use letters instead of numbers...

Any help?

I am trying to avoid, "double looping".
OR maybe someone can alleviate my anxiety of "over looping" by telling me that it is unavoidable at certain times.

Cheers